# firebase notification stops working (android)

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

So yesterday I implemented code to receive notification on my device. I tested it with firebase notification composer and it worked.

It worked when my app was in background and also when my app was in foreground.

Today is not working anymore (same foreground and background). I forgot to back up my code. But I am pretty sure that I did not change anything in code.

I have two classes.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{


    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        storeToken(refreshedToken);
        Log.d("test",refreshedToken);

    }

    private void storeToken(String token){
        SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        sharedPrefManager.storeToken(token);
    }

}
```

MyFirebaseMessaginService.class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    private static final String TAG = "testtest";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                //scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                // handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }


        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kostik.meet">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/charizard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In notification composer I am setting latest device token. 
I tested in on multiple devices with same result. (Of course I set different token for different device in notification composer)
Notification composer shows status completed.

So when app is in foreground onMessageReceived is never called and when app is in background Notification message never shows.

Comment: Post error stacktrace.

Comment: are u passing the correct token while sending the notification ?? when u reinstall the token changes

Comment: Yes I am. I know about that.

Comment: check the device in which u r testing has valid net connection

Answer (score 0):

I created new firebase project and changed google-service.json file and now it works.